# kotlin webview android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference ko

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview

I'm having this error does anyone know how to fix it?
Any help is welcome. thank you. i'm using fragment

```
class ForumFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {



      ERROR LINE->  val wv = webView.findViewById(R.id.webView) as WebView

        webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
        webView.clearView();
        webView.measure(100, 100);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true)
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_forum, container, false)
    }

  }
```

LOGCAT ERROR ->

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                at .fragments.ForumFragment.onCreateView(ForumFragment.kt:45
```

Comment: In `onCreateView` first you must inflate your layout which returns `view`, and then using that `view` instantiate your webview

Comment: Could you post the layout of the fragment you're using? Where are you accessing the instance of `webView` from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ForumFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var v: View
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_list_project, container, false)
        val wv = v.findViewById(R.id.webView) as WebView

        wv.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
        wv.clearView();
        wv.measure(100, 100);
        wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true)
        wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        return v

    }
```